# Get System Date Format String Win32

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to get the system current date format string like ("dd-mm-yyyy" , "mm/dd/yyyy" ect.

GetDateFormat()  API returns the formatted string like "12-09-2015" but need string like "dd-mm-yyyy"

C# solution

```
string sysFormat = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
```

But I need in Win32.

Comment: look in the registry, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International`. You probably need `sShortDate`

Comment: Never look in the registry. There is a real API for this: [`GetLocaleInfoEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318103%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @andlabs, can you please detail downed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of format strings currently applicable, by enumerating them. This is done through [EnumDateFormats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317810.aspx). Note, that there can be (and usually is) more than one, so you will have to decide, which one to pick<sup>1)</sup>.

The following code returns the system's default short dateformat pattern:

```
static std::list<std::wstring> g_DateFormats;
BOOL CALLBACK EnumDateFormatsProc( _In_ LPWSTR lpDateFormatString ) {
    // Store each format in the global list of dateformats.
    g_DateFormats.push_back( lpDateFormatString );
    return TRUE;
}

std::wstring GetShortDatePattern() {
    if ( g_DateFormats.size() == 0 &&
         // Enumerate all system default short dateformats; EnumDateFormatsProc is
         // called for each dateformat.
         !::EnumDateFormatsW( EnumDateFormatsProc,
                              LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,
                              DATE_SHORTDATE ) ) {
        throw std::runtime_error( "EnumDateFormatsW" );
    }
    // There can be more than one short date format. Arbitrarily pick the first one:
    return g_DateFormats.front();
}

int main() {
    const std::wstring strShortFormat = GetShortDatePattern();
    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> *The .NET implementation does the same thing. From its list of candidates, it arbitrarily picks the first one.*

Answer (score -1):

You can use [time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f4c8f33.aspx) function together with [localtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf12f0hc.aspx) function.

Example code:

```
//#include <time.h>
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
time(&rawtime);
timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
//The years are since 1900 according the documentation, so add 1900 to the actual year result.
char cDate[255] = {};
sprintf(cDate, "Today is: %d-%d-%d", timeinfo->tm_mday, timeinfo->tm_mon, timeinfo->tm_year + 1900);
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question. The question is, how to get the currently selected **format string**, not how to use an arbitrary format string, to construct a string representation of a datetime.